# Why does gnome-terminal display a unicode escape character?

Tags: vim, terminal, gnome, escape-characters

More specifically, in Vim if I press escape twice (and under some other circumstances too) I get this character appearing:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1b/index.htm

It can be replicated by typing echo, then Ctrl-V, then escape

Here's what it looks like:

[image: terminal output]

I've tried changing the font and TERM setting, neither of which make a difference. No other terminals I've tried (xterm, urxvt, that KDE console) have the same behaviour.

What I'd like to know is whether this is a bug or intended behaviour, and if there's any workarounds

Comment: On a related note, for anyone who is having the same issue with Vim, the cause is the `visualbell` setting.

Placing `set novisualbell` in the vimrc seems to sort it

Comment: This is a known bug in vte (gnome-terminal): https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403130.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's intended behavior. No typeface provides a glyph for that codepoint, so the font engine generates the default "codepoint-in-a-box" glyph.

Comment: So the intended behaviour of all of the other terminal applications is to suppress it?

Comment: They use a different font engine.

Comment: @benwh: I'm not sure if there's even an "intended behavior" for this specific character. `ESC` is the first byte of all "escape sequences" that control the terminal's behavior (move cursor, set colors, etc) – so technically, when a program outputs a bare `ESC`, the terminal sees it as an invalid escape sequence and can choose to print it out, or to discard it.

Comment: how come all of the other terminal emulators know what to do with it?

Comment: @QuinnWilson: They don't. They simply don't display anything since that's the behavior of their font engines.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar problem because I had modified my .vimrc some time in the past to play nicely with MINTTY.  Strangely, those modifications are not usually problematic in gnome-terminal, but they are if it's running on ARM.

In my case, commenting out this section of my .vimrc fixed it:

```
let &t_ti.="\e[1 q"                                                                                                   
let &t_SI.="\e[5 q"                                                                                                   
let &t_EI.="\e[1 q"                                                                                                   
let &t_te.="\e[0 q"
```

If you've modified those values, you might try removing those modifications